# Get full entities with Hibernate envers

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I am using the following to get the revisions of an entity:

```
AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager())
            .createQuery()
            .forRevisionsOfEntity(Car.class, true, true)
            .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(carId))
            .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().asc())
            .getResultList()
```

But the fields that are not marked with @Audited are null, when they should have values.

Will I have to merge the unaudited values manually if I want a fully filled entity?

Comment: What gives you the impression that the non-audited fields would be non-null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Envers only populates the instance with the data from the audit history tables.  The only exception to this is when an association isn't audited and implies that the related entity is to be pulled from the main table.

So if you had the following entity definition:

```
@Entity
public class SimpleEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  private String data1;
  @Audited
  private String data2;
  ...
}
```

The returned instance from Envers would only have populated the `id` and `data2` fields.  The value for `data1` would be null as the field was not designated to be audited by Envers.

If you expect a fully-populated entity, then yes you'd need to look into merging existing state with the audit state somehow.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I ended up doing, manually merge them to get full entities.